# Make filtering on rule

Tags: windows, linux, makefile

I have a make rule like

`app.o: app.c b.c a.c h.h file.list`

I am using rule `$^`  to do some action on all dependency. 
But I want to filter based on file extension on dependency. 
How can I do that ?

I want a variable

`k = (which contain only .c file from dependency list )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using *GNU Make*, than

```
$(filter %.c,$^)
```

will do the trick (filter returns all words matching given pattern from a list, filter-out returns the non-matching ones). If you are using some more primitive make, you'll have to resort to

```
APP_O_C_DEPS = app.c b.c a.c
APP_O_NONC_DEPS = h.h file.list
app.o: $(APP_O_C_DEPS) $(APP_O_NONC_DEPS)
        ...
```

*Note:* The way variables work in Make allows you to say

```
c_deps = $(filter %.c,$^)
app.o: app.c b.c a.c h.h file.list
    something $(c_deps)
```

and it will expand to the .c dependencies of current target.